# Intuition behind kernel and linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a vector space and a linear map $T: V \longrightarrow V$.
If $ker(T \circ T) = ker(T \circ T \circ T)$ then $ker(T) = ker(T \circ T) $

The statement is not true - i'm not looking for a counter example i'm trying to understand **why???**

I **emphasize** the word **why(what is the intuition behind it)** that's what important for me to understand.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the representative matrix of a linear map you will easily see that this assertion doesnt hold. Just assume a nilpotent matrix $0\neq A\in\mathbb{R^{2\times 2}}$ with $A^2=0$.

The intuition is that you transform i.e. $V=\mathbb{R^2}$ in the first step on a line. This happens by using a matrix with $rank(A)=1$. In the next step the line will shrink to zero for a nilpotent matrix.

I can recommend to watch the playlist from 3Blue1Brown about linear algebra, if you dont have a geometric intuition. In chapter 3 he introduces linear transformation and in chapter 6 the situation i mentioned.

Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab